# Schema not displayed when implementing depends with request in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

With code below schema `UserCreateData` is not displayed in swagger.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
from starlette.requests import Request

app = FastAPI()


class UserCreateData(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: EmailStr  # unique
    username: str  # unique


async def validate_user_create_data(request: Request) -> UserCreateData:
    body = await request.body()
    validation_errors = []

    try:
        user_create_data = UserCreateData.parse_raw(body)
    except ValidationError as e:
        pydantic_validation_errors = e.errors()
        validation_errors.extend(pydantic_validation_errors)

    # complex validation with nested models (uniqueness validation, etc)
    # add complex validation errors to validation_errors
    # raise ALL validation errors if validation_errors exist

    return user_create_data


@app.post('/users')
async def create_user(user_create_data: UserCreateData = Depends(validate_user_create_data)):
    ...
```

[image]

How to fix it? Is `openapi_extra` the only way?

Comment: The problem is that you don't really depend on UserCreateData (as it's not an argument to any of your dependencies), you only depend on `request` - the only thing that can be automagically inferred is that there is a `UserCreateData` made somewhere, but the only input dependency is the request itself. If you depend on `UserCreateData` being sent, use that as the argument, not just `request`.

Comment: I cannot use UserCreateData as an argument because if there is a validation error in schema complex validation is not being ran. So I explicitly user_create_data = UserCreateData.parse_raw(body) and catch errors and the do another validation

Comment: In that case it seems that you actually don't expect `UserCreateData` as the type, but something else? Or a union between different types? Or some other limitation? You'll have to give an example of what you're actually trying to do in that case, since it's hard for other people to know how that differs from what `UserCreateData` has been defined as (since your validation then seems to be doing something else than what the definition of `UserCreateData` is, and it would be wrong to say that `UserCreateData` represents the expected format in that case.

Comment: I do expect `UserCreateData`. Beside structure and types validation (made by pydantic) I need to check `username`, `email` uniqueness in database table (by myself). They say uniqueness validation should not be done by pydantic so I put it dependency after pydantic (`user_create_data = UserCreateData.parse_raw(body)`) validation but have faced schema displaying issue

Comment: But why can't your `validate_user_create_data` method take an instance of `UserCreateData` as its input? That's just the input validation - you can then perform any additional validation inside the `validate_user_create_data` function. It's unclear to me _why_ you need `request` as the input and perform `parse_raw` yourself, since you can take `UserCreateData` as the input format. There is nothing saying you can't do that in the dependency function, and then perform additional validation inside that function.

Comment: Because if there is a single validation error found by Pydantic complex validation won't be ran. You could try to see this